# Finding Stack Exchange site for mathematical writing

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question on mathematical writing. Which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate for this?

**Writing** seems to be the ideal choice. But, mathematical writing seems to be not on agreement with academic writing in many matters. See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/447697/120721) and its [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/447722/120721) on math.stackexchange for instance.

Comment: I don't understand. The question you cite, whose topic is mathematical writing, is located at [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Unless you're saying the question is *off topic* there—then it's *on topic* there and surely where similar questions should be asked.

Comment: You haven't given any reason why [writing.se] isn't a good place to try... the community there will be happy I'm sure to help you to shape your questions such that they fit there.

Comment: @JasonBassford, then you should say Math SE is the correct site. But that question is only a soft question there for sure.

Comment: @curiousdannii, i am afraid mathematical writing doesn't quite fit in Writing SE. Only questions on mathematical writing I could find in SE is in math SE and they are all soft-questions there.

Comment: What do you mean by *"mathematical writing"*?

Comment: pizza_static_void_main  gave a good advice. @and_myself gave the answer I was looking for in a comment. I can not vote up answers or comments yet :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For questions like the one you posted, [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) would be best because it seems the question you linked got *very* well received on mathematics and was definitely related to math. If you're having a hard time figuring out if it is related enough to writing to be on-topic on [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/), you should probably just post it on mathematics where you know it's on-topic.

Comment: Looks like [article-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article-writing) on Maths.SE is the tag the OP is looking for...